# Работа со строкой

Tags: python, строки

Здравствуйте. У меня есть одна очень длинная строка, мне нужно достать из нее десять цифр, которые идут после слова "tick=***********". Как возможно это сделать средствами Python 2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое - с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
re.findall(r'tick=(\d{10})', str)
```

Comment: Поддерживаю. Ещё можно найти index вхождения и взять последующие 10 символов, желательно проверив их на isdigit. Но я бы делал регулярной.

Answer (score 3):

Не надо усложнять...

```
print('my tick=1234567890zzz'.split('tick=')[1][:10])
```

Comment: Это круто, только если условие задачи стабильно выполняется. Если в строке вообще не будет tick=,  если будет несколько tick= или после него будет не 10 цифр - ваше решение выдаст неверный результат или приведет к ошибке.

    >>> print('my tic-k=1234567890zzz'.split('tick=')[1][:10])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Никогда не додумывайте задание. Я сам этим иногда грешу, и всегда потом жалею. Вообще, самое лучшее техзадание - это юнит-тесты.